# Why don't we say "a thousand of people" but "thousands of people" and "a thousand people"?

Tags: grammar, numbers

I notice that the phrases "a thousand people" and "thousands of people" are both correct, but I've never heard "a thousand of people".

First of all, is it correct to say "a thousand of people"?

I think it has to do with "people" being indefinite, but if this is the case, why is it correct to say "thousands of people"?

I understand that we can say "a thousand of the people who...", so let's exclude this case.

Thanks!

Comment: We don't really say "a thousand of [anything]" in a lot of contexts. E.g., one wouldn't say "I've read a thousand of books" or "I have a thousand of dollars".

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, I know it doesn't sound natural, but cannot seem to explain why (colloquially, grammatically, etc.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Except, perhaps, the phrase “a thousand of anything” itself.

Comment: @Lawrence - The context I had in mind where it makes sense is when placing an order: "Give me a thousand of this and a thousand of that", or, "I'd like a thousand of the green, a thousand of the blue, and five thousand of the red." (But really the point of my original comment was that I didn't think it was clear whether the OP was trying to focus specifically on *people* or not.)

Comment: @nnnnnn No not at all. I was just using "people" as an example. Can be anything.

Also, I was more focused on the nouns (or noun phrases) following "of" which are indefinite, e.g. some random people, some random blue or red items. Your examples make sense, because "this", "that", "the blue", "the red" are definite; in other words, we know exactly which object(s) is being talked about.

Comment: It's purely a matter of it being unidiomatic. *A ton of people* is fine. Both *ton* and *thousand* are nouns that provide a measure of something. So, the grammar is fine. It's just the fact that we *don't* that makes it sound wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Noun vs Adjective**

In these sentences the term is being used as an adjective:

> A thousand people
>
> > Tall people
> > Short people

In these sentences the term is being used as a noun

> Thousands of people
>
> > A group of people
> > A collection of people

For this scope, the "of" only comes after a noun, not an adjective. "A tall of people," is grammatically equivalent to "A thousand of people", and "A group people" is grammatically equivalent to "A thousands people", all of which are incorrect.

"Of" is a **preposition** and can be defined for its usage in this context as

> expressing the relationship between a scale or measure and a value.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Tyler!